How can I modify the \dfrac command to automatically display thousands separators?
In small math classes, students are asked to respect the thousand separators, like this:

This forces me to use the \num{} command from the siunitx package in each argument of the \dfrac command.
How can I define a new \dfrac command so that I don't have to do this and write \newfrac{1}{10000000} instead of \dfrac{1}{\num{10000000}}?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=FR}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\num{0.27609390226}=\dfrac{2}{10}+\dfrac{7}{100}+\dfrac{6}{1000}+\dfrac{9}{100000}+\dfrac{3}{1000000}+\dfrac{9}{10000000}\\
+\dfrac{2}{1000000000}+\dfrac{2}{10000000000}+\dfrac{6}{100000000000}
\end{multline*}


\begin{multline*}
\num{0.27609390226}=\dfrac{2}{10}+\dfrac{7}{100}+\dfrac{6}{\num{1000}}+\dfrac{9}{\num{100000}}+\dfrac{3}{\num{1000000}}+\dfrac{9}{\num{10000000}}\\
+\dfrac{2}{\num{1000000000}}+\dfrac{2}{\num{10000000000}}+\dfrac{6}{\num{100000000000}}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}


Something like \newcommand*{\numfrac}[2]{\dfrac{\num{#1}}{\num{#2}}}?

Yes, something like that.

\dfrac is doing nothing theer you could use \frac and get the same display.

@DavidCarlisle If I remember correctly, \frac writes fractions in smaller characters in my documents. But if there's no difference, why are there two commands, \frac and \dfrac?

@AndréC dfrac (which should be used sparingly) forces displaystyle fractions so will use the large form even in a superscript, frac chooses a suitable form depending on the context but the context here is displaystyle so it will use the same display as dfrac.

@DavidCarlisle Okay, but personally, when I write a fraction in a text, with \frac in 12 pt font, I can't see the numbers and even if \dfrac produces characters that are too large, I agree, at least it's readable even by visually impaired students. Is there a way of modifying the font size so that in a text it's larger than that produced by \frac and smaller than that produced by \dfrac?

you are testing in textstyle I assume? but the example here that I commented on  is in displaystyle.

@DavidCarlisle Yes, in text style, it's too small. I now understand that in maths mode, dfrac does nothing more than frac.

@AndréC Luciole  at 20pt is good for visually impaired people but  I don't know a matching math font and for example it has awful curly braces { and }.

@user691586 Thank you, unless I'm mistaken, to use a font from your Windows or Linux system, you have to use LuaLaTeX. If not, is there a LaTeX version of this font?

@AndréC I don't think there is a packaging of the font for use with traditional TeX/LaTeX via pdftex/pdflatex. Indeed you have to use xelatex or lualatex.

You can define \newfrac in this way:
\NewDocumentCommand{\newfrac}{m m}{\dfrac{\num{#1}}{\num{#2}}}

This will set both the numerator and denominator using siunitx's \num.
Alternatively, if you want to keep using \dfrac, use
\RenewDocumentCommand{\dfrac}{m m}{\genfrac{}{}{}0{\num{#1}}{\num{#2}}}


Perfect, thank you. Unless I'm mistaken, is \RenewDocumentCommand in the xparse package? Is it now part of the LaTeX core?

@AndréC: It's part of the core, yes, so no need to explicitly include \usepackage{xparse}.

Does the space inm m hold any significance? It seems as spaces do matter usually in documents that mm would be more expected (even if completely equivalent), else it seems to encourage usage as \newfrac {A} {B} so it encourages to put spaces a bit everywhere, which yes do not have have any impact if macro fetches two arguments but perhaps not in general.  I have always felt that what is completely lacking from all books serving as introduction to LaTeX is a frank and complete discussion of spaces, and that the style of LaTeX3 programming encourages people not to care about them.

@user691586: I split them out because there can be multicharacter argument specifications (like +m or !o or O{stuff} or d()). Even if I use single-character argument specifications, it's just a habit. It makes it more clear if these are separated with a space (\NewDocumentCommand{\cmd}{+m !o O{stuff} d()}{...}) rather than not (\NewDocumentCommand{\cmd}{+m!oO{stuff}d()}{...}).

@Werner thanks indeed it does make sense, I understand. Maybe I should have practiced myself these new functionalities prior to make my question/remark...
